# Define Type as an any of Class.Properties

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm wondering if it's possible to define a type that is set as any property of an object (class). In a way that it would act kinda like an enumeration.

(X = Property of this Data class, i.e. Data.Prop1 or Data.Prop2)

```
public class Data
{
    public bool Prop1 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop2 { get; set; }

    public bool Add(X name)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        Data d = new Data();
        d.Add(Data.Prop1);
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this?  I feel like there isn't, but I thought I'd ask.

Thanks,

Thanks everyone for trying to understand.  Here is some additional clarification (I will mention that I don't think this is possible).

Let's say I have the following:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
}

public class Faculty
{
    private List<Student> students;

    static public string GetValue(int id, [Student.Property] prop)
    {
        return students.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault().prop;
    }
}
```

Then when you call the Faculty.GetValue(1, [This would be a completion list like it is for enums]) - You could select one and that is passed to the function and then the function has someway of handling the [Property] that was passed in so that it can return that property from the object.

Again, I feel like this is not possible, just wanted to check before moving on.

Thanks again,

Comment: Are you looking for [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)?

Comment: The question really doesn't make sense, feels like an XY problem.

Comment: What's wrong with making it an enum and make `d` a set of enum values?

Comment: I have read this 3 times and still have no idea what your question is, can you maybe add a bit more detail

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a Dictionary, since you are looking for a Get/Set type of behavior for a named set of values.

Comment: I did not get the question, but you can change X to T as generic

Comment: In C# is no subsystem to passing properties by names/keys. The @Damien_the_Unbelievers answer is close as can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be far better done by allowing a `Func<>` to be passed:

```
public class Faculty
{
    private List<Student> students;

    static public T GetValue<T>(int id, Func<Student,T> prop)
    {
        return prop(students.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault());
    }
}
```

And then the caller just has to pass `x=>x.Prop1` rather than your proposed `Prop1`. (Of course, they have the flexibility to choose something other than a lambda to specify the `Func<>`)

(There are issues here if `Student` is a reference type, as it is here, and `FirstOrDefault` returns `null`, but those same issues existed in the OP's proposed code also. How these should be dealt with is unclear since using `FirstOrDefault` kind of brought `null`s into scope when I wouldn't necessarily expect them)